# Ошибка в правильном SQL запросе

Tags: sql, mariadb

Вроде правильный запрос:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db1;
USE db1;
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
   ID int identity not null,
   name_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

, но выдаёт ошибку

> Query Error 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds 
>   to your MariaDB server version for the 
>   right syntax to use near 'USE db1; 
>   CREATE TABLE tb1 ( 
>   ID int identity not null, 
>   name_id VARCHAR(24) NOT N' at line 2

Comment: В mysql нет identity вместо него auto_increment. Могут быть и другие проблемы, связанные с тем, что вы берете синтаксис MS SQL, а используете его на MySQL

Comment: А ещё, судя по сообщению, используется метод, не поддерживающий multi-query.

Comment: Вы уже попробовали заменить  `identity` на `auto_increment` ?